# Dart 'The function isn't defined' although defined

Tags: dart, flutter

How would I properly access the `_runThisFunction(...)` within the `onTap()`?

```
...

class _DealList extends State<DealList> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  void _runThisFunction() async {
    print('Run me')
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _loadingDeals,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data['deals'].length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final Map deal = snapshot.data['deals'][index];

                    return _getDealItem(deal, context);
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
      },
    );
  }
}

Container _getDealItem(Map deal, context) {
  return new Container(
    height: 90.0,
    child: Material(
      child: InkWell(
        child: _getDealRow(deal), // <-- this renders the row with the `deal` object
        onTap: () {
          // Below call fails
          // 'The function isn't defined'
          _runThisFunction();

        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Seems like this is not your actual because there is a semicolon missing.

Comment: yep, there are syntax errors everywhere. Missing comma, missing semicolons. Where is param declared? etc etc.

I cant make an answer without all the code.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Missing semicolon? Lemme try and present a much better code snippet

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Added more code to explain the process

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that is that you are out of scope.
*Little hint*: The word *"function"* always indicates that the function you are trying to call is ***not*** part of a **class** and the keyword *"method"* shows you that the function you are trying to call is part of a class.

In your case, `_runThisFunction` is defined *inside of `_DealList`*, but you are trying to call it from outside.
You either need to move `_getDealItem` into `_DealList` or `_runThisFunction` out.

```
/// In this case both methods [_runThisFunction()] and [_getDealItem()] are defined inside [_DealList].
class _DealList extends State<DealList> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
   void _runThisFunction() ...

   Container _getDealItem() ...
}
```

---

```
/// In this case both functions are defined globally.
void _runThisFunction() ...

Container _getDealItem() ...
```

You wil need to make sure that you also apply the same logic to `_getDealRow` and other nested calls.